# Comodines dentro de script en bash

Tags: linux, bash, script

Necesito hacer una verificación de sintaxis de una variable que se introduce por teclado.
Copio un ejemplo de lo que deseo hacer:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pedimos que se introduzca hh_hh_nombre (ejemplo 13_14_Pepe)
read -p "Introduza hh_hh_nombre :" valor

# Verificamos que la variable introducida se haya escrito con la sintaxis correcta,
# es decir, que tenga 2 caracteres , seguido de guion bajo, seguido de 2 caracteres, seguido de otro guion y 
# despues el nombre

if [ $valor == ??_??_* ]; then 

        echo "ok"

    else 
        echo "nok"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente el problema que tenías era mínimo, simplemente en la validación  `if [ $valor == ??_??_* ]; then`  debías cerrarlo en doble corchete, de la siguiente manera.

En el manual de referencia, sección [Construcciones condicionales](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs), podrás encontrar más información sobre este tema. `[[ ... ]]`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pedimos que se introduzca hh_hh_nombre (ejemplo 13_14_Pepe)
read -p "Introduza hh_hh_nombre :" valor

# Verificamos que la variable introducida se haya escrito con la sintaxis correcta,
# es decir, que tenga 2 caracteres , seguido de guion bajo, seguido de 2 caracteres, seguido de otro guion y 
# despues el nombre

if [[ $valor == ??_??_* ]]; then 

        echo "ok"

    else 
        echo "nok"
fi
```

Espero sea de ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Ese era mi problema :)